# Блокировка записи в таблице на время редактирования

Tags: php, mysql

Привет всем, господа! По топику, если быть точнее, то больше не блокировка, а **раз**блокировка такой записи в БД, хотя и первое, и второе - взаимосвязано. Тема далеко не новая, однако хотелось бы её обсудить в плане оптимальной реализации.

*Идём пошагово:* **User#1** открыл какую-то запись (скажем статью) и принялся её упорно редактировать, дописывая вручную первый томик "Войны и Мир". При открытии таковой, блокируем запись: толи в отдельное поле ставим флаг (1 - редактируется, 0 - свободно), толи в какое-то поле время начала редактирования, или какой-то свой способ - не суть важно. Минуту спустя, **User#2** так же изъявил огромное желание дополнить статью, но был мягко послан по уже известной причине блокировки, посему сидит, ждёт и курит. Теперь ситуация может развиваться по разным сценариям:

1. **В идеале** - **User#1** дописал чего хотел и сохранил статейку. Снимаем блок с записи и **User#2**, со спокойной душой, может приступать к своему творчеству.
2. **"Неадекват"** - **User#1**, написав первую половину томика "Война и Мир", вспомнил, что на предыдущей странице, он забыл поставить в чате смайлик Марии Ивановне. *В итоге*: history.go(-1), статья осталась заблокированна. Естественно звонок мне, в то время, как я стоя в забитой маршрутке, одной рукой поднимаю с мобилки сервак - не есть гуд. Под категорию "неадеквата", так же попадают те, кто оставил статью открытой и ушел на пять часов обедать, те, кто просто закрыл браузер не сохранив статью и т.д.
3. **Форс-мажор** - просто рубануло свет, а UPS, как на зло, вчера променяли на новый чехол для iPhone. В принципе, результат схож с предыдущим пунктом.

Пока вижу следующее, но всё же смущающее меня решение данной проблемы: **User#1** открыл запись >> ставим в доп. поле "**last_update**" текущее время >> к примеру, ajax-ом стучимся каждые 1-2 минуты, обновляя поле "**last_update**" с автосохранением уже проделанных изменений >> если в течении минут 10-15, $pdo->rowCount() нам возвращает "0", то автоматом снимаем блокировку с записи. Или, если со страницы **User#1** уйдет, то при открытии статьи другим, будет так же сверяться текущее время и время последнего апдейта  >> **User#2** получает доступ, а второму выводим сообщение, что "слоупокам" придется перезагрузить статью и ждать, если она в руках другого.

На данный момент - как-то так, но за последние дни я так замахался, что скорее всего, нормальное решение уже не генерируется в мозгу. Буду рад выслушать любые, пусть даже бредовые идеи, если таковыми богаты ;)

Comment: Может логичнее сделать аналог СКВ. Храним историю хэшей статьи плюс версии статьи из разных "веток". Если сделан "коммит", а хэш не совпадает с заголовком, то делается дифф и предлагается смержить. После мержа остаётся только головная версия статьи и хэши смерженных веток.  
Сложнее, чем просто блокировка, но зато удобнее, так как блокировки нет.

Comment: @ReinRaus, не очень удобный вариант для моего случая. Наверно стоило бы указать сразу, но редактироваться будут, так сказать анкеты, в которых более 70 полей и придётся сравнивать все их хеши. К тому же, если дать возможность двоим и более (*а такое скорее всего и будет*) пользователям доступ, и после внесения изменений опоздавшему сообщить, что он в пролете, то будет совсем не хорошо.

Comment: ну так можно совместить два варианта. серверная часть проверяет только кто первый закоммитился, тот и молодец. а на клиенте оповещать, что кто-то редактирует уже эту запись, хотите открыть все равно? так в шарепоинте реализовано кстати, там лок не монопольный, чекаут можно сделать для любого элемента. если второй человек захочет закоммититься, либо дифф выдавать (хоть трехсторонний, base-mine-their), либо предложить при попытке коммита обновить данные сначала.

Comment: Почитайте про оптимистическую и пессимистическую блокировки.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, да, надо будет рассмотреть этот вариант, бладарррю.

@shurik, спасибо, я в курсе, но немножко не то, что нужно.

Comment: Я не понимаю диф чего из чем? Если версий штук десять уже накопилось статьи Никто не успел смержить, поясните.